# Genius me: broke raphael.js draw for IE8 --> What'd I do?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, svg, raphael

Got this code from here http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/drawtool2.php. Runs great in IE when I tested it on that site... I made a few mods to it in order to change the cursor style and stroke color, etc... but my version does not work in IE. I know this is a ton of code to look over, but I could really use a fresh set of eyes (or 20) to help me see what I've changed that breaks the funct in IE8.

ORIGINAL VERSION:

```
        var g_masterPathArray;
        var g_masterDrawingBox;
        var g_masterPaper;

        function initDrawing() {
            var g_masterPaper = Raphael(10,10,700,500);

            var masterBackground = g_masterPaper.rect(10,10,600,400);
            masterBackground.attr("fill", "#eee");
            masterBackground.mousemove(function (event) {
                var evt = event;
                var IE = document.all?true:false;
                var x, y;
                if (IE) {
                    x = evt.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft +
                    document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
                    y = evt.clientY + document.body.scrollTop +
                    document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                }
                else {
                    x = evt.pageX;
                    y = evt.pageY;
                }

                // subtract paper coords on page
                this.ox = x - 10;
                this.oy = y - 10;
            });

            var start = function () {
                g_masterPathArray = new Array();
            },
            move = function (dx, dy) {
                if (g_masterPathArray.length == 0) {
                    g_masterPathArray[0] = ["M",this.ox,this.oy];
                    g_masterDrawingBox = g_masterPaper.path(g_masterPathArray);
                    g_masterDrawingBox.attr({stroke: "#000000","stroke-width": 3});
                }
                else
                    g_masterPathArray[g_masterPathArray.length] =["L",this.ox,this.oy];

                g_masterDrawingBox.attr({path: g_masterPathArray});
            },
            up = function () {
                ;
            };

            masterBackground.drag(move, start, up);
            return g_masterPaper;
        }
```

MY VERSION:

```
var g_masterPathArray;
var g_masterDrawingBox;
var g_masterPaper;
var paperOffset;
var dataObj = {};
var sketchpadArray = new Array();
var backgroundArray = new Array();
var evtIndex;
var stylus = { 'utensils' : [
{// Pen default settings
    'stroke':'#000',
    'strokeWidth': 3,
    'strokeOpacity':1,
    'cursor':'url('+jsThemeDir+'pix/pencil-flip.png), auto;'
},
{// Highlight default settings
    'stroke':'#EDF30C',
    'strokeWidth':10,
    'strokeOpacity':0.5,
    'cursor':'url('+jsThemeDir+'pix/highlight-flip.png), auto'
}
 ]
};// end stylus

jQuery('div.sketchpad').each( function(index,element) {

  var g_masterPaper = Raphael(element, jQuery( element ).css('width') , jQuery( element).css('height') );
  sketchpadArray.push( g_masterPaper );
  sketchpadArray[index].currentUtensil = 0;
  var masterBackground = g_masterPaper.rect(0,0, jQuery(element).css('width'),jQuery(element).css('height'));
  masterBackground.attr("fill", "#fff");// Background color of drawing rectangle
  masterBackground.attr("fill-opacity",0);// Opacity of this bgcolor
  masterBackground.attr('stroke-width',0);// Turn off rectangle border. We will give this to the svg in the css.

  backgroundArray.push( masterBackground );
  var drawSet = sketchpadArray[index].set();
  sketchpadArray[index].drawSet = drawSet;

  //masterBackground.attr('cursor','url('+jsThemeDir+'pix/pencil-flip.png)');// Cursor. We can apply this to the svg in css and avoid hardcoding here. 
  masterBackground.mousemove(function (event) {

    evtIndex = jQuery('svg').index( jQuery(event.target).parent('svg') );

    var evt = event;
    var IE = document.all?true:false;
    var x, y;
    if (IE) {
      x = evt.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft +
    document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      y = evt.clientY + document.body.scrollTop +
    document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    else {
      x = evt.pageX;
      y = evt.pageY;
    }

    // subtract paper coords on page
    paperOffset = jQuery( element ).offset();// get paper x and paper y
    this.ox = x - paperOffset.left;
    this.oy = y - paperOffset.top;
  });

  var start = function () {
    g_masterPathArray = new Array();
  },
  move = function (dx, dy) {
    if (g_masterPathArray.length == 0) {
      g_masterPathArray[0] = ["M",this.ox,this.oy];
      g_masterDrawingBox = g_masterPaper.path(g_masterPathArray);
      g_masterDrawingBox.attr({ 
        'stroke': stylus.utensils[sketchpadArray[evtIndex].currentUtensil].stroke,
        'stroke-width': stylus.utensils[sketchpadArray[evtIndex].currentUtensil].strokeWidth,
    'stroke-opacity': stylus.utensils[sketchpadArray[evtIndex].currentUtensil].strokeOpacity,
        'stroke-linecap':'round',
        'stroke-linejoin':'round'
      });    //stroke: "#000000","stroke-width": 3,"stroke-linecap":"round"});
    }
    else {
      g_masterPathArray[g_masterPathArray.length] =["L",this.ox,this.oy];
      g_masterDrawingBox.attr({path: g_masterPathArray});
      //console.log( masterbackgroundArray[masterBackground] );
  sketchpadArray[evtIndex].drawSet.push(g_masterDrawingBox);
  jQuery('.sketchpad:eq(0)').next('.sketchpad-controls-cont').find('.undo-btn, .clear-btn').removeClass('disabled');

    }
  },
  up = function () {
;
  };

  masterBackground.drag(move, start, up);

  // Draw immediate elements now! use a for/each to call each, sending appropriate obj
  drawInit(index, 'draw-on-load');
  initCorrect(index, 'draw-show-correct');

  return g_masterPaper;
});
```

Comment: For starters are there any errors?  Have you tried commenting out your mods one by one to determine which is at fault?

Comment: jsThemeDir is undefined.

Comment: thank you for looking!! jsThemeDir is defined in theme header. there are no errors.

Comment: Okay, well are you getting any errors?

Comment: No errors at all. No errors about scripts loading, no errors when I try to drag on the drawing area... just nothing is drawn...

Comment: Can you provide the markup?  Or a fiddle? Or link so I can play with it?

Comment: just had another user test in IE9, and apparently what I've got works in IE9... this begins to look more & more contentious. how does one go about debugging something like this? some nuance of event support in IE8?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/emicin/14 (added some css to make it look decent..., fixed some issues with calls to other functs.. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

OK, Chasbeen was correct in pointing back to the dimensions for init. Init of Raphael() object seemed to work fine in drawing width and height from parent using jquery:

```
var g_masterPaper = Raphael(element, jQuery( element ).css('width') , jQuery( element).css('height') );
```

But... when I did the same thing with the child rectangle that was going to detect mousemove, problems resulted:

```
var masterBackground = g_masterPaper.rect(0,0, jQuery(element).css('width'),jQuery(element).css('height'));
```

What I found was that I had to get the val using jquery, strip off the 'px' from the string, re-type as Number, and *then* IE would accept it to init that rectangle.

```
var width = jQuery( element ).css('width');
width = width.replace('px','');
width = Number( width );

var height = jQuery( element ).css('height');
height = height.replace('px','');
height = Number( height );
```

New init for masterBackground looks like this:

```
var masterBackground = g_masterPaper.rect(0,0,width,height);
```

I assume that masterBackground was being created with width and height of 0 previously and this is why no mousemove was being detected.

In addition, I was trying to identify index of the drawing box in case there was more than one in a given page. I was trying to get it using

```
jQuery( mycollection ).index( jQuery( event.target ) );
```

This will not work with IE8. You have to get the event target obj in a different way:

```
var eventTarget = event.target || event.srcElement;
```

Answer (score 1):

You got it off my site. I'm thinking it works on Ie in it's raw state
Guessing it might be that you are not creating a Raphael canvas
Ie is fussy about where it's initiated
Start with a basic page that draws 1 circle make notes on where you placed the generic Raphael call
Where was initDrawing called from?
Will it work Tom document.ready()?
Excuse spelling ipod

Comment: Don't understand what you mean by not creating a raphael canvas.. is this not correct?: `var g_masterPaper = Raphael(element, jQuery( element ).css('width') , jQuery( element).css('height') );
`

Comment: all these scripts are being loaded in the page footer, so I'm not sure that document.ready() pertains... ?

Comment: paper = Raphael(canvas_div, 500, 300);
     paper.canvas.style.position = "absolute";
     paper.canvas.style.zIndex = "1";

Comment: Sorry ignore the above. Your waiting for the browser to be sufficiently ready to see the raphael javascript. It takes IE longer and sometimes the Raphael declaration is not valid.

Comment: I have a hunch it's got to do with my trying to add funct to switch stroke to a "highlight" & back to "pen"... will keep digging...